# Run Command cmd through

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

How can I run this command in c#

> telalertc -i bilal -m "Test Message"

```
string command = "telalertc -i bilal -m  "Test";

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
  new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", " /c " + command);

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procStartInfo.Domain = "*.*.*.*";

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

proc.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

How can I run this command using *console application* C#

Comment: Why are you running `cmd` instead of `telalertc` directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start `telalertc` start it, not `cmd`:

```
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    FileName = "telalertc",
    Arguments = " -i bilal -m \"Test Message\"",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Domain = "*.*.*.*" // do you really want this?
  };

  // Wrap IDisposable into using
  using (var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procStartInfo)) {
    // First wait for completeness  
    proc.WaitForExit();
    // Then read results
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
```

Comment: You may not have right(s) to either run the exe, or exe itself doesn't have right to access some resource (e.g. `bilal`)

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed: you may want to use `RedirectStandardError` in order to inspect messages from the exe